# Insert data from one table data to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `TAB1` and `TAB2`. I want to insert data in `TAB2` in a particular column. I want to insert data that has to be fetched from the `TAB1` on `WHERE` condition. If fethced data is there, then insert data in `TAB2`. If NOT, insert blank in `TAB2`

Here I am talking about single column only. I am inserting some other data also. Can it happen in as single SQL Query. I am using Oracle.

Here is my demo code. I need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TAB1('value1','value2',?)

 if exists(select king from TAB2 where queen='yash' )

  ?=select king from TAB2 where queen='yash'

 if not exists 
  ?=''
```

`TAB1` and `TAB2` are having different type of columns.

```
 TAB1                           TAB2
--------                     -----------------
col1 col2 col3  col4             col1 king Queen  
-----------------            ----------------

 1    jan  King   Robin            1    Alex   yash
 2    Feb  King2  Hood             2    Jhon   Shakthi
```

Now I want to insert data in TAB1 from TAB2 with where condition 
Something like this

```
insert into  TAB1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
        values(5,'MArch',King7, select king From TAB2 where Queen='yash')
```

If select king From TAB2 where `Queen='yash'` returns `'Alex'` then that has to be inserted if not blank value has to be inserted.

```
  Here Queen column is Unique column .. So you can expect single row data only.

TAB1 and TAB2 having different column names and different column Types
```

Comment: what did your means with this statement
"if NOT insert blank in TAB2"

Comment: Okay, can you give us some sample contents from `TAB2`, and what you want inserted in `TAB1` in each case?  What's supposed to happen when there are multiple rows where `queen = 'yash'`?  What happens if there are _no_ rows where that's true, but the table has multiple other entries?  If there are multiple entries, what happens when some of them have a matching value, but not all of them?

Answer (score 4):

```
TAB2
-----------------
 col1 king  Queen  
----------------

  1   Alex  yash
  2   Jhon  Shakthi
  3   Fred  Maya
```

---

```
insert into  TAB1(col1,col2,col3,col4, col5)
        select 5, -- If you are tring to use an auto incremental value, I recommend you to use a trigger and Sequence on the table
              'March',
              'King7', 
              king , 
              col1 -- Col1 is used to get an Idea which row caused the Insert
             From 
        TAB2 where Queen='yash';



 TAB1                           
--------------------------------           
col1 col2   col3   col4    col5         
--------------------------------           
 5   March  King7  Alex    1
```

---

```
insert into  TAB1(col1,col2,col3,col4, col5)
        select 5, 
              'March',
              'King7', 
              case when Queen='yash' then  king  else '' end, 
              col1 
             From 
        TAB2 ;


--------------------------------           
col1 col2   col3   col4    col5         
--------------------------------           
 5   March  King7  Alex    1     
 5   March  King7  ''      2     
 5   March  King7  ''      3
```

---

```
---- removing insert to Col5 column
 insert into  TAB1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
        select
            distinct
            5, 
              'March',
              'King7', 
              case when Queen='yash' then  king  else '' end
              From 
        TAB2 ;

--------------------------           
col1 col2   col3   col4           
--------------------------           
 5   March  King7  Alex    
 5   March  King7  ''
```

---

```
 insert into  TAB1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
        select
            distinct
            5,
            case when Queen='yash' then 'March' else '' end,
            case when Queen='yash' then 'King7' else '' end, 
            case when Queen='yash' then  king   else '' end
              From 
        TAB2 ;

--------------------------           
col1 col2   col3   col4           
--------------------------           
 5   March  King7  Alex    
 5   ''     ''     ''
```

Comment: I am considering first case.
Thank you Yours is making sense.. Here column 'value1' is unique.. and  `SELECT 'somevalue' , 'somevalue' , CASE WHEN queen ='yash' THEN king ELSE '' END
FROM tab2;` this one returning the duplicate values.. for that I have used `distinct` .. But still somehow I am missing my requirment...As if `YASH` is there I am having two records from `SELECT 'somevalue' , 'somevalue' , CASE WHEN queen ='yash' THEN king ELSE '' END
FROM tab2;` this statement. Here `Queen` column in TAB2 is unique...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'insert blank' you mean don't do an insert, you probably want to look at doing an INSERT SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO TAB1( ... )
SELECT ... FROM TAB2
WHERE ...
```

Comment: The fields in `TAB1` and `TAB2` are different.. is that ur solution possible ?

Comment: @looser, Yes You can insert it as, `INSERT INTO tab1(col3, col4, ..) SELECT col1, col2, .. FROM TAB2 WHERE <condition>`. But make sure that the datatype are same.

Comment: What is the value for "value1" and "Value2" in TAB1. Does it these column need to be inserted from TAB2 or it some default value.

Comment: Hi,What you can try is to use INSERT INTO <TABLENAME>(COLUMNS) SELECT <COLUMNS> FROM <TABLENANE> WHERE <CONDITIONS>. It will only include those records which fulfills the criterias.Thank You

Comment: @GunjanShakya `value1` and `value2` are different values .. THose are not form `TAB2` only `valueX`is from `TAB2`.